# Error: Error parsing triggers while deploying cloud functions - Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-functions

I'm using `renderToString` function from `react-dom` (on my server side). The code looks like (+/-):

```
import Home from './app/containers/Home';
const app = express();

app.get('**', (req, res) => {
  const html = renderToString(<Home />);
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200');
  res.send(html);
});
```

Everything goes smooth, until I try to deploy it on the server.

**Example error** in  the console:

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'store/Home/actions'
```

#### When it appears?

If I change my path to some other component, **which does not use** any other components (only modules from node, like `react` or `react-redux`) it works **correctly**.

But if I try to use some component which uses other components and imports them, e.g.:

`var _CreateUser = require('components/Pages/CreateUser');` (it's in the rendered component)

Now it will fail with error:

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'components/Pages/CreateUser'
```

So currently Im stuck, because I have to use my whole app on server side, not just a single component which doesn't import anything :)

Why does it work this way? Why does it fail? Is it bad webpack config fail?

Looking forward for any help. Thank you.

**Note**, as I said above, if I render to string some component with any imports (that doesn't use any other component in it) - the server side rendering works fine and Im able to see the *renderedToString* content before page loads.

[image]

Comment: 1) What OS in your server and your local/dev computer? 2) did you installed all packages at server side (the same version as in your dev enviroment)?

Comment: How do you deploy? Just copy paste folder? Or do you use git?

Comment: @sultan 1) Local win7. Server? I don't really know... 2) I've installed all packages that im using on server side rendering. 3) I deploy it with `firebase deploy`, Im not using git

Answer (score 3):

Everywhere you import local modules you need to include the directory in the path otherwise it will search node_modules for a named package and ultimately fail.

```
require('./store/Home/actions');
```

Or:

```
import HomeActions from './store/Home/actions';
```

...depending on which import style you're using.  An accurate directory is always needed as a part of the import/require statement.

Comment: Same thing happens. `Cannot find module './components/Pages/CreateUser'`

Comment: Could you show the code for CreateUser?  If not check out the export statement.  If you're using **require** (commonJS) it should be `module.exports = something` or if you're using **import** (es2015+) you'd need to export with `export default myModuleName` or something similar.  They're not interchangeable.  [https://medium.com/@brianleroux/es6-modules-amd-and-commonjs-c1acefbe6fc0](Medium Article on that topic)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. So at the end I have `exports.default = enhance(CreateUser);` and at the beginning `Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});`

Comment: Okay, that seems to be the problem.  You shouldn't need the defineProperty and you're mixing commonJS modules with es6 imports.

Here's a good page that shows the difference.  [require vs. import](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f)

Answer (score 2):

You're using a relative path, `cd` into and deploy from the functions directory so it's correct.

Comment: I still get the same error :( I tried to deploy from like every possible directory...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `Home` component is inside `functions/app/containers/Home` and you need access to the file `functions/app/store/Home/actions`.

From your `containers/Home` file, you need to *go up* two directories to the `app` folder, then *go down* two directories to correct file. So

```
import HomeActions from '../../store/Home/actions'`.
```

Each `../` represents going up one directory to the parent folder. We went from

`functions/app/containers/Home` to

`functions/app/containers/` to

`functions/app` and then we can specify which path to continue on from there with

`store/Home/actions`